# Why is this code running so slowly?

Tags: c++, optimization, profiling

I am seriously stumped by this code, I have run gprof and found that the program spends 40% of the time in the contains() function which runs about 8000 times.  The program itself takes a total of 15 seconds to run. Does anyone have any idea why it takes so long, or what else it could be?

```
// Check a list to see if it contains a tile object at x,y
bool contains(std::list<struct Tile>* list, int x, int y){
  std::list<struct Tile>::iterator it;
  for(it = list->begin(); it != list->end(); it++){
    if((*it).x == x && (*it).y == y){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Lists are not efficient for searching. Why not use vectors?

Comment: Well, how long is your list?  A linear search is not particularly efficient (but it's about as good as you'll get on a linked list.)

Comment: And drop the `struct`, just `Tile`. It's cleaner.

Comment: +1 for "I have run gprof". Heed the answers though!

Comment: Also, `for (Tile t : list)` could be more efficient (caches `list->end()`).

Comment: The simplest way to answer this is not by asking people. All you will get is guesses. And while `gprof` is better than nothing, it is about 1% better. Rather, run it under a debugger and single-step it, at the disassembly level. After you step it through a few hundred instructions, you will know exactly what you need to do to make it faster.

Comment: If this is something like a tile map, store it in a two-dimensional array or `vector`. If it's sparse, use an `unordered_map<TileCoords, Tile>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), it is about 100 times faster to traverse since it is cache-friendly. Vector push_back has O(1) amortized difficulty, just like list. Vectors are bad for middle insert anyhow.
Also [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) are designed for fast search.

Comment: Whilst I agree with your general premise, 100x seems unlikely.  A cache line (on x86) is 64 bytes.  Even if `T` is only 8 bytes, that's a maximum of 8x the main memory fetches required...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: as well as the x86 assumption, that's assuming nothing starts out in cache.  Given the 8 byte data assumption we're talking up to 8x as many values staying in the cache which could - for some access patterns and data sizes - avoid a lot of main memory fetches, as well as contiguous memory usage working better with any speculative pre-fetching....

Comment: @TonyD: Yes that's fair.  (Although for very large datasets which exceed the cache, I guess the asymptotic ratio difference tends toward the 8x...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Agreed.  Separately, you can binary search in a pre-sorted `vector` which may or may not be practical for dakillakan's app.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Don't forget that x86 predicts memory accesses. After the first few reads, the memory controller will be doing read-aheads. Plus modern RAM has better latencies for linear access (pages which have been idle for a while are put to sleep)

Comment: Random memory access is about 100 ticks. Long vector access is nearly free due to hardware prefetch. So in worst case (nothing in cache) it is. For all-in-cache lists traverse is about 2-6 times slower than vectors traverse due to low level CPU problems (data recursion).

Comment: @user3161163: Pre-fetching, yes, definitely.  But I guess it depends whether you're limited by latency or throughput?  Pre-fetch doesn't reduce the total load on the memory bus.  Although it's definitely true that there's no way to hide latency with a linked-list traversal.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: On my Core i3 L1 cache is 17 Gb/s, RAM is 8 Gb/s. Ram has just 2 times lower throughput but about 100 times worse latency. RAM throughput is not a major bottleneck. RAM latency is. Also for list of small objects there is a cache line overhead. CPU can't request less than 64 bytes from RAM.